# Reversing row direction for every 2nd child using Bourbon neat

Tags: html, layout, sass, bourbon, neat

I'm attempting to reverse the row layout for every 2nd child using Bourbon Neat `reset-layout-direction` mixin. However, this does not seem to be working using the nth-child pseudo selector. What am I doing wrong? Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/ggyzYd)

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="project">
    <div class="project__image">image</div>
    <div class="project__text">text</div>
  </div>

   <div class="project">
    <div class="project__image">image</div>
    <div class="project__text">text</div>
  </div>

   <div class="project">
    <div class="project__image">image</div>
    <div class="project__text">text</div>
  </div>

   <div class="project">
    <div class="project__image">image</div>
    <div class="project__text">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.project{
  @include row();
  //@include row($direction: RTL); //Works here and rightly reverses all rows. 

  .project__image, .project__text {
    background: tint(red,50%);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 130px;
    @include span-columns(3 of 6);
    @include omega(2n);
  }

  &:nth-child(2n + 2){
        color: red;
    //@include row($direction: RTL); Doesn't work here
        }
}
```

Edit: I've come up with this solution but its just silly. I shouldnt need to repeat styles in this way - [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/OWYVWM)

Answer (score 0):

I see two options. First, we can use `:nth-child` to target the even rows, but make it work by also using it to target the odd rows. Still some duplicate looking code to make Neat work, but at least moving the shared code into a new rule to reduce duplication.

HTML

```
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="project">
    <div class="project__image">image</div>
    <div class="project__text">text</div>
  </div>

   <div class="project">
    <div class="project__image">image</div>
    <div class="project__text">text</div>
  </div>
  <!-- And so on... -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
// Visual styles here.
.project {
  @include row($direction: LTR);

  .project__image,
  .project__text {
    background: tint(red,50%);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 130px;
  }
}

// These are your odd rows. Even minus one.
.project:nth-child(2n-1) {
  //@include row($direction: RTL); //Works here and rightly reverses all rows. 
  .project__image,
  .project__text {
    @include span-columns(3 of 6);
    @include omega(2n);
  }
}

These are your even rows.
.project:nth-child(2n) {
  @include row($direction: RTL);

  .project__image,
  .project__text {
    @include span-columns(3 of 6);
    @include omega(2n);
  }
}
```

You could also use Flexbox. Same HTML markup as above. We're using Neat for the proper column widths, then removing the margin from all children. Then Flexbox is used to separate the columns, leaving a gutter. On even rows, we use `flex-direction: row-reverse;` to reverse the two sides.

CSS

```
.project {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  .project__image,
  .project__text {
    @include span-columns(3 of 6);
    @include omega(2n);
    margin-right: 0;
    background: tint(red,50%);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 130px;
  }
}

.project:nth-child(2n) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Definitely less code. CodePen: https://codepen.io/alexbea/pen/jyjqwV

Comment: I've that tried flexbox option and row reverse doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: I added a Pen to my answer with the demo built out.